# Facebook App - Add Tester through API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-chatbot

Is it possible to add a Facebook user to the "Tester" role on a Facebook app through one of the Facebook APIs, without an admin user having to manually add the user to the "Tester" role on the App settings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API Reference says yes, and there is example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/roles#publish

Be aware:

> A user access token for any admin of the app is required.

Comment: yo are welcome, please don´t forget to accept the answer ;)